# Manga where the cultivator asking normal people (who are cosplaying cultivators) for advice

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

Manga is about a cultivator who thinks that in the modern world everyone is a cultivator (but they are only pretending by creating films, streaming, etc). He created a pill which gives a dog the ability to talk and even beat the current master. He is asking for advice for further cultivation sitting in the internet cafe and a famous (girl) streamer helping him (but she thinks that every video from the MC is a cool montage).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: You note this as "isekai". What world did the main character come from? Why were they transported to another world? Do you remember anything about ethnicity, hairstyle, clothing, hair color, etc about the main character or the streamer?

Comment: I don't remember the exact beginning of the story, but it starts when MC is already isekaied and reborn in the body of the child(6 y.o). After that old man picks up the child at his house(the old man is just an ordinary old guy, but MC thinks of him as deity). So MC ask old man for guidence in the cultivation, old man think that the child watched a lot of TV shows(in that time it was famous to pretend cultivators for movies and streams), so the old man pretends to teach the child, but actually, he's guidance forward child to actually become cultivator(Old man was super surprised). After an old

Comment: Decided to travel to the nearest city, and become more familiar with the modern world, he doesn't know about mobile phones nor internet

Comment: https://desu.me/data/manga/covers/preview/4219.jpg
He is very similar to this style
And super unick detail, he created pills for cultivation and by mistake one of the pill eat an ordinary dog, and become very powerful and talkative

Comment: He is not fighting with anyone because he think that everyone in the modern world top cultivators(because they are cosplaying cultivators and using SJI movie to add effects of the destruction , explosion etc)

Comment: That sounds sick. Hope we find it. Amen 

Comment: If need more details I can write some more

Comment: @NatsumeSoseki i found it...."I became Invincible after Descending" ...ohhhhh shit ...it was so difficult

Answer (score 2):

i readed your description and also the comment section. where you described mc detail. it's manhua called "[Descending The Mountain As Invincible](https://manhuafast.com/manga/descending-the-mountain-as-invincible-all-chapters/)".

point match:

> MC is already isekaied and reborn in the body of the child(6 y.o).
> After that old man picks up the child at his house(the old man is just
> an ordinary old guy, but MC thinks of him as deity). So MC ask old man
> for guidence in the cultivation, old man think that the child watched
> a lot of TV shows(in that time it was famous to pretend cultivators
> for movies and streams), so the old man pretends to teach the child,
> but actually, he's guidance forward child to actually become
> cultivator(Old man was super surprised).

Comment: Yes, thank you, its exactly what i searching for